# VBA Excel External Workbook Evaluation

Tags: excel, vba

I am so rusty with VBA that I thought it might be better to ask here for a sample sheet\snippit.

I need to take data from another WORKBOOK (slave) and evaluate it.
I will look at cell 1A through whatever the maximum in A is, from slave, and...
a "update") if the data from a exists on the master sheet, replace cell (master)X:Y with (slave)X:Y
b "add") if the data from A on slave doesn't exist on the master, add the entire row of data from slave to master, at the bottom of master.
c "remove") if the data from A on master exists but doesn't on the slave, move the entire row on master to another sheet on master

So far I've gotten as far as pulling the data from one workbook into another.

Thank you in advance!

Adam

Comment: Take a look through the links in the **Related** section to the right. These would be the same links you were presented with when you asked your question. Anyone asking for help coding a problem is **expected** to show original effort.

Comment: Actually I did.  I've been looking through this stuff for most of the evening.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this so far.  Now I need to strip out the unneeded columns, which will be easy.  The hard part which I will most likely need help with is evaluating the contents of all the cells in row 1 of the updated sheet, with row 1 of the existing sheet, and following the conditions I've established earlier.

Sub NeMasterData61_Button1_Click()

```
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim wsMaster As String
Dim wbSlave As Workbook
Dim wsSlave As String
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim LastSlaveRow As Integer
Dim LastSlaveColumn As Integer

'Declare the Worksheet names
wsMaster = "Update"
wsSlave = "Sheet1"
'Set the wbMaster workbook
Set wbMaster = ActiveWorkbook
'Clear any previous updates - .ClearContents doesn't remove formatting
wbMaster.Sheets(wsMaster).UsedRange.Delete
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", 1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
'Set the wbSlave workbook
Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
'Find Last Row and Column used
LastSlaveRow = wbSlave.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastSlaveColumn = wbSlave.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
'Copy the range of data from the slave sheet
wbSlave.Sheets(wsSlave).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastSlaveRow, LastSlaveColumn)).Copy
'Paste the data into the master sheet
wbMaster.Sheets(wsMaster).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
'Close wbSlave:
wbSlave.Close

End Sub
```